# Selecting group level row on selecting all event on ui-grid

Tags: javascript, angularjs, ui-grid, angular-grid

I am trying to react on event when user clicks on **select all** event on header of ui-grid. All rows do get selected, which is expected behavior, but high level group rows are not selected which in my opinion is counter-intuitive for a user. 
You can see example here: http://embed.plnkr.co/rUsK0LfGF3ws8vhsc9sR/

[image: Example]

I know that triggered event is:

```
gridApi.selection.on.rowSelectionChangedBatch($scope,function(rows){
          // do something
});
```

But when I iterate through **rows** passed to function I don't see the ones that are group level rows so I could select them. Is there a way to do this?

Comment: Check my answer below

Answer (score 0):

As per the documentation [HERE](http://ui-grid.info/docs/#/tutorial/209_grouping)

**Group header rows cannot be edited, and if using the selection feature, cannot be selected. They can, however, be exported.**

Have a look at the below screen shot which is taken from Complex grouping found [here](http://ui-grid.info/docs/#/tutorial/320_complex_grouping)[image]